# Чи тотожні значення напруга і напруження?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, віддієслівні-іменники

Натрапила на одне [дослідження](http://publications.lnu.edu.ua/bulletins/index.php/journalism/article/viewFile/4315/4350) щодо вживання синонімів *напруження* і *напруга*. Висновок у ньому зроблено такий:

> На думку редакторів видавництв, між якими часто ведуться дискусії щодо
>   нормативного слововживання у певному контексті, лексему «напруга»
>   треба вживати як технічний, фізичний термін.
>
> А в інших випадках замість російського «напряжение» писати
>   «напруження», зокрема, «альтераційне напруження», «увіднотонове
>   напруження», «каденційне напруження», «напруження у вимові»,
>   «політичне напруження», «соціальне напруження».

Там же наведено посилання на українські тлумачні словники, словник синонімів, російсько-український словник, в яких таке однозначне розмежування відсутнє.
Які є підстави для вибору слова *напруження* стосовно, скажімо, психологічних процесів, якщо на практиці слово "напруга" є широко застосовуваним? ([Приклад](http://studentam.net.ua/content/view/10881/86/)).

Comment: Є також загальшіне питання: [«Як бути з віддієслівними іменниками на -ння, -ття?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3084). Що, однак, може не враховувати якісь специфічні нюанси для конкретних слів. **І досі не має відповіді**.

Comment: Родич-запитанье: [Різниця між словами **супровід** та **супроводження**](/q/3552/585)

Answer (score 2):

Щоб дати відповідь на це питання варто звернутися до СУМу, де є обидва цих слова ([напруга](http://sum.in.ua/s/naprugha) та [напруження](http://sum.in.ua/s/napruzhennja)). Звідти ми розуміємо, що ці слова можуть бути синонімами, однак коли ідеться про "фізичний стан електрики, яким визначають силу струму" потрібно вживати слово "напруга". Також, можемо переглянути виноску з "[Уроків державної мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53405/26134.html)":

> напруження – напруга – напруженість Перших два іменники вживаються
>   паралельно, але в розумінні “фізичний стан електрики, яким визначають
>   силу струму” виступає переважно напруга. Напруженість – властивість,
>   стан напруженого. Ослаблення міжнародної напруженості, напруженість
>   уваги.

Також коли ми говоримо про термінологію цих двох слів, варто звернутися до статті [В. Грещука](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine24-23.pdf):

> Слова *напруга* і *напруження* з’явилися в українській мові в другій половині XIX ст. як рівнозначні, але в процесі співфункціонування намітилося розходження в їх семантичних структурах. Іменник *напруження* на відміну від спільнокореневого слова *напруга* розвинув переносне значення «скрутне, важке становище де-небудь, з чим-небудь»: «У роки, коли
>   буває великий урожай, створюється.. *напруження* з робочою силою і транспортом» (Хлібороб України).
>
> Треба відзначити і термінологічне значення іменників *напруга* і *напруження*. Обидва вони вживаються на позначення величини тиску або розтягання, що виникає в твердому тілі внаслідок зовнішніх впливів (сили, температури і т. ін.): «Точний розподіл внутрішніх механічних *напружень* необхідний при конструюванні п’єзо-трансформаторів та інших складних пристроїв» (Знання та праця); «За Уралом дні і ночі заграв виснули підпруги, сталь засліплювала очі, сталь найвищої *напруги*» (М. Рудь). Але значення «фізичний стан електрики, яким визначають силу струму» властиве тільки іменнику *напруга*: «Усю гору перетинають ажурні металеві опори, по яких біжать проводи високої *напруги*» (О. Корнійчук).

Comment: Вибачте, зараз трохи поправлю